# select even column is null oracle

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, select

the command below is my sql select command;

```
sqlcommand = "SELECT * FROM INVENTORY WHERE LOWER(SAPNO) LIKE LOWER('" + sapNo + "%') AND LOWER(PARTDESC) LIKE LOWER('" + partDesc + "%') AND LOWER(PARTNO) LIKE LOWER('" + partNo + "%') AND MINQTY = '" + minQty + "' AND QOH = '" + QOH + "' AND LOWER(CATEGORY) LIKE LOWER('" + category + "%') AND LOWER(EQUIPMENT) LIKE LOWER('" + equipment + "%')";
```

example like category and equipment is confirm null. and the rest have the value. How can I select the row even though category and equipment is null?? because I using this comment whenever equipment and category is null, the data wont be shown!

your comment is much appreciated!! 
TQ

Comment: add some OR conditions ?

Comment: @Adrian OPPS, how come I never think of that! Thanks!! do u mind write your answer at below? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add some OR conditions in order to return rows that can have specific values null.

```
AND (LOWER(CATEGORY) LIKE LOWER('" + category + "%') OR CATEGORY IS NULL) AND (LOWER(EQUIPMENT) LIKE LOWER('" + equipment + "%') OR EQUIPMENT IS NULL)
```